# emacs equivalent to vim's word completion with ctrl P

Tags: emacs

With vim, I can autocomplete and get a list of any words in the buffer by hitting C-p while in insert mode.

Is there a similar command in emacs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `hippie-expand` command for completion. To bind it to <kbd>Alt + /</kbd>, use

```
(global-set-key "\M-/" 'hippie-expand)
```

Comment: slightly nicer is the kbd macro (function?) - `(global-set-key (kbd "M-/") 'hippie-expand)`

Answer (score 9):

In addition to `hippie-expand`, mentioned by @choroba, here are two other standard Emacs word-completion methods:

- `M-/` or `C-M-/` -- Dynamic abbrev expansion (aka `dabbrev`). See the Emacs manual, node [`Dynamic Abbrev Expansion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dynamic-Abbrevs.html#Dynamic-Abbrevs).
- `M-RET` or `C-RET` in `dynamic-completion-mode` -- Standard Emacs library `completion.el`.

Library **`completion.el`** is old and apparently little known, but it works great.  You can complete not only to words in the same buffer but to words (program symbols etc.) that you have used in the *past*, including past Emacs sessions.

Your most frequently used completions are prioritized.  What you do when `dynamic-completion-mode` is on is recorded in a "database" on disk: the words you type or traverse, etc.  To make good use of library `completion.el`, read the `Commentary` in the file. There is no other doc for it, but the `Commentary` is pretty clear (if not totally up-to-date).

Library [**Icicles**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) enhances the use of both of the above word-completion methods, [`dabbrev`](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Completion_in_Other_Buffers#DynamicAbbreviation) and [`complete`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Completion_in_Other_Buffers#DynamicCompletionUsingCompletionEL).  When there are multiple possible completions it lets you choose one using better matching possibilities (e.g. substring, regexp, not just prefix).